# Why go server responds with 307 when CORS used

Tags: reactjs, go, cors

I have a very simple app with CORS middleware that seem to work correctly and preflight request works as expected. But for some reason server responds with 307 on actual request. Reproduces in browser, from postman works correclty.

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(CORSMiddleware())

    accountsGroup := router.Group("/accounts")
    accountsGroup.POST("/", postAccount)
    router.Run("localhost:8080")
}

func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,HEAD,PATCH, OPTIONS, GET, PUT")

    if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        c.AbortWithStatus(204)
        return
    }

    c.Next()
}


func postAccount(c *gin.Context) {
    response := gin.H{"id": 1}
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusCreated, response)
}
```

preflight response

[image: preflight]

actual request

[image: actual request]

server logs

```
[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on localhost:8080
[GIN] 2022/04/17 - 16:50:45 | 204 |            0s |       127.0.0.1 | OPTIONS  "/accounts"
[GIN-debug] redirecting request 307: /accounts/ --> /accounts/
[GIN] 2022/04/17 - 16:52:55 | 204 |            0s |       127.0.0.1 | OPTIONS  "/accounts"
[GIN-debug] redirecting request 307: /accounts/ --> /accounts/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've registered the handler under `/accounts/` but you're making the request to `/accounts`. That coupled with the [`RedirectTrailingSlash`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.RedirectTrailingSlash) setting which is by default set to `true` is what causes the redirect.

> Enables automatic redirection if the current route can't be matched
> but a handler for the path with (without) the trailing slash exists.
> For example if `/foo/` is requested but a route only exists for `/foo`,
> the client is redirected to `/foo` with http status code `301` for `GET`
> requests and `307` for all other request methods.

Comment: Is that right? Based on the bottom screenshot, the request is sent to `/accounts` (no trailing slash), which is the route the OP registered the handler on, and it results in a redirect to `/accounts/`.

Comment: `accountsGroup.POST("/", postAccount)` I don't use gin but i assume this is equivalent to `/accounts/` given how `accountGroups` was created, is it not?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Sorry!

Comment: I see now that it worked with postman because it adds trailing slash. Never knew a single slash could make such a difference.